# How to override html codes in wordpress?

Tags: php, child-theme, html, parent-theme

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array('list-article', 'clearfix') ); ?>>

<div class="list-article-thumb">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'onepress-blog-small' );
        } else {
            echo '<img alt="" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/placholder2.png' .'">';
        }
        ?>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="list-article-content">
    <div class="list-article-meta">
        <?php the_category(' / '); ?>
    </div>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-excerpt">
        <?php
            the_excerpt();
        ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'onepress' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div>
```

this is the code.

I need override all codes inside

```
<div class="list-article-content">
</div>
```

because html codes are not surrounded by if(!functionname()){}

I don't know how to override this code.

I tried to copy and paste into functions.php in child theme but it just duplicated html code.

So, how to override this html code to child theme without editing parent theme?

Comment: What file is this code coming from in the parent theme?

Comment: @SummerDeveloper URL of the code file is  parent_theme/template-parts/content-list.php

Comment: And what calls that? You need to look at the docs on child themes you can't overwrite by simply copy and pasting into the functions.php...

Comment: @SummerDeveloper thank you that you tried to answer my question. I just template-parts folder in my child theme and created and moved copied file to there. and worked!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question. 
Just create folder with same name (in my case name is template-parts) and pasted copied php file to the folder.